# Is there any timeout/expiry period implemented for Global Inbox Notifications?

Tags: support, notifications, global-inbox

As the title says, is there any timeout period or expiry period implemented for Global Inbox Notifications?

For example, lets say I post this question and go away for 2weeks / 2months / 2years / 2decades(?) / ... and receive a couple of comments on this post along with a couple of answers to it, also receive a couple of chat pings, comments to other posts of mine, notification for some badges, etc.

I would generally be notified about it when I next visit the Stack Exchange Network. However, if I come back after the continued absence of such a long-period specified above, will the Inbox still notify me about all the stuff which happened in between. Or they expire after a specified period of time and I would have to struggle to reconcile things myself?

And, is there any limit on the maximum number of notifications I would receive?

Comment: So, how are things in 2033?